# override /etc/vimrc.local

Tags: vimrc

I am working on a machine where I do not have root access, and I do not like some of the global vim settings (in `/etc/vimrc.local`).

How can I disable these in my personal `.vimrc`?

Specifically, the global file has many

```
autocmd FileType XXX setlocal ...
```

which differ from my preferences. Besides redefining every filetype in my local file, is there any other way to fix this?

**EDIT** more information:

The relevant portion of `/etc/vimrc.local` is

```
""" indentation schema
set autoindent              " enable automatic indentation
" set default indentation scheme
filetype plugin indent on   " indent based on filetype
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set expandtab               " insert spaces instead of tab
" set language-specific indentation schema
if has("autocmd")
  " use real tabs in Makefiles
  autocmd FileType make setlocal tabstop=8 shiftwidth=8 softtabstop=0 noexpandtab
  " indentation is tab/width=8,4 in C's KNF style
  autocmd FileType c setlocal tabstop=8 shiftwidth=8 softtabstop=4 noexpandtab
  autocmd FileType cpp setlocal tabstop=8 shiftwidth=8 softtabstop=4 noexpandtab
  " indentation is two spaces in Ruby
  autocmd FileType ruby setlocal tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 expandtab
  " indentation for shell scripts
  autocmd FileType sh setlocal tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 expandtab
  " indentation is four spaces in python - also set by python.vim
  autocmd FileType python setlocal tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 expandtab
endif
```

In my case, I don't like the `c`/`cpp` rules defined here; I'm wondering what I can put in my `.vimrc` to override. Currently, my `.vimrc` has

```
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set autoindent
set expandtab " spaces instead of tabs
```

but the `autocmd` options are taking precedence.

Comment: Can you [edit] in the file content? It may help to identify other solutions. In general, I’m not aware of a way to skip the system vimrc, only override it.

Comment: Well, you can always do `vim -u NONE` and then `:source ~/.vimrc`.

Comment: But I don't want to ignore _all_ the settings in the global file. Then I need to pick individually turn all of them back on in my local file.

Comment: As a temporary fix, I have redefined the `autocmd FileType ...` for those filetypes where I want different settings. It's annoying, manual, and not robust, but it'll have to do.

Answer (score 1):

The only "clean" way I see, is to replicate the autocmds in your own setup and correct the option values with them (you already mentioned that in the comments). Autocmds for the same event (here `FileType`) are executed in the order they are defined.

So you have to add the following to your `vimrc`:

```
autocmd FileType c setlocal ....
```

Do you have contact to the person(s) responsible for `/etc/vimrc.local`? If yes, you could ask them to wrap the autocmds in a `augroup` like:

```
if has("autocmd")
  augroup vimrc_local
    " use real tabs in Makefiles
    autocmd FileType make setlocal tabstop=8 shiftwidth=8 softtabstop=0 noexpandtab
    ...
  augroup END
endif
```

Now all the autocmds from `vimrc.local` are grouped under `vimrc_local`. With that you could add the following to your `vimrc`:

```
autocmd! vimrc_local
```

This will delete all autocmds from the group `vimrc_local`.

---

**Could I use `autocmd!` without a `augroup`?**

Yes, but this will delete all autocommands in the "default" group. The docs (`:help autocmd-remove`) contains warnings like:

> **Warning:** You should normally not do this without a group, it breaks plugins, syntax highlighting, etc.

You *might* get away with it, if you use it as the first command in your `vimrc` and no plugins or syntax settings are in the global `vimrc`.

You could test yourself with the following.

Open Vim and execute

```
:put =execute('autocmd')
```

This will put all defined autocmds into the current buffer. Save it as `a1` and exit.

Add `autocmd!` as the first line in your `vimrc`.

Again open Vim and execute:

```
:put =execute('autocmd')
```

Save the buffer as `a2`.

Now you can diff `a1` and `a2` and see which autocmds were removed. Then you decide for yourself, whether this might work for you.

If you see some strange behavior later on, disable the `autocmd!` to check if that might be the reason.

Anyway I would recommend to talk to the vimrc.local guys first.